# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" as my function is defined. Can't seem to find any solutions online or anything similar...

I have the following html:

```
<div class="signup-wrapper1" id="signup-wrapper1" style="display:inline">
    <button class="button_primary" type="submit">Sign up with Google</button>
    <p>Alternatively, <a href="#!" onclick="togglingNow();">Sign Up With Email</a>. </p>
</div>
```

And the following javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
function togglingNow() { 
    document.getElementByID('signup-wrapper1').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>;
```

Any help appreciated - am new so let me know if I have missed something that is obvious to you guys...

Answer (score 4):

`document.getElementByID` is `undefined`. The `D` should be lowercase.

Comment: I still get the same error with a lowercase D...
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined togglingNow"

Comment: @Del: Then the problem is somewhere else, because the (fixed) code you posted works: http://jsfiddle.net/4ba4f5rc/. Also don't change your question to include the solutions from the answers. That makes the answer look out of place. However, feel free to *add* additional information.

Comment: Even with the above code I get the same error-I've just tried it in a new file containing nothing else.
And I'm not sure why all the negatives?

Comment: @Del: All that screenshot shows is that you're getting an error. Again: It's not from the code in the question.